# Cookies in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, lumen, lumen-5.2

Since the last version (5.2), cookies are disabled in Lumen. I'm currently making an API in Lumen with JWT authentication.

To secure my application from CSRF attacks I need to set a csrf cookie. But what is the best way to handle that now?

Answer (score 2):

VerifyCsrfToken Middleware was removed in this [commit](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/commit/b63c9525740082c68752efd4bb5aa421dda73213).

From Lumen 5.2 documentation:

> Lumen 5.2 represents a more decided shift towards focusing on stateless APIs.

So, if you need Csrf Token verification, you have to implement it storing it in a meta tag or inside a JWT payload as a [private claim](https://jwt.io/introduction/#payload) (you will need to implement the new claim, i.e.: [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Contracts/Claim.php)).

If it was removed, there's probably a good reason. Here I let some links that maybe can help you move on.

[CSRF Token necessary when using Stateless(= Sessionless) Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357182/csrf-token-necessary-when-using-stateless-sessionless-authentication)

[Where to store JWT in browser? How to protect against CSRF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067251/where-to-store-jwt-in-browser-how-to-protect-against-csrf)

https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage#post-2748616172